# Recall from nltk.metrics.score returning None

Tags: nltk

I'm trying to calculate the precision and recall using the nltk.metrics.score (http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/metrics/scores.html) with my NLTK.NaiveBayesClassifier.

However, I stumble upon the error:

```
"unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType".
```

which I suspect is from my 10-fold cross-validation where in some reference sets, there are zero negative (the data set is a bit imbalanced where 87% of it is positive).

According to nltk.metrics.score,

```
def precision(reference, test):
   "Given a set of reference values and a set of test values, return
   the fraction of test values that appear in the reference set.
   In particular, return card(``reference`` intersection 
   ``test``)/card(``test``).
   If ``test`` is empty, then return None."
```

It seems that some of my 10-fold set is returning recall as None since there are no Negative in the reference set. Any idea on how to approach this problem?

My full code is as follow:

```
trainfeats = negfeats + posfeats    
n = 10 # 5-fold cross-validation    

subset_size = len(trainfeats) // n
accuracy = []
pos_precision = []
pos_recall = []
neg_precision = []
neg_recall = []
pos_fmeasure = []
neg_fmeasure = []
cv_count = 1
for i in range(n):        
    testing_this_round = trainfeats[i*subset_size:][:subset_size]
    training_this_round = trainfeats[:i*subset_size] +         trainfeats[(i+1)*subset_size:]
    classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_this_round)

    refsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
    testsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for i, (feats, label) in enumerate(testing_this_round):
        refsets[label].add(i)
        observed = classifier.classify(feats)
        testsets[observed].add(i)

    cv_accuracy = nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testing_this_round)
    cv_pos_precision = precision(refsets['Positive'], testsets['Positive'])
    cv_pos_recall = recall(refsets['Positive'], testsets['Positive'])
    cv_pos_fmeasure = f_measure(refsets['Positive'], testsets['Positive'])
    cv_neg_precision = precision(refsets['Negative'], testsets['Negative'])
    cv_neg_recall = recall(refsets['Negative'], testsets['Negative'])
    cv_neg_fmeasure =  f_measure(refsets['Negative'], testsets['Negative'])

    accuracy.append(cv_accuracy)
    pos_precision.append(cv_pos_precision)
    pos_recall.append(cv_pos_recall)
    neg_precision.append(cv_neg_precision)
    neg_recall.append(cv_neg_recall)
    pos_fmeasure.append(cv_pos_fmeasure)
    neg_fmeasure.append(cv_neg_fmeasure)

    cv_count += 1

print('---------------------------------------')
print('N-FOLD CROSS VALIDATION RESULT ' + '(' + 'Naive Bayes' + ')')
print('---------------------------------------')
print('accuracy:', sum(accuracy) / n)
print('precision', (sum(pos_precision)/n + sum(neg_precision)/n) / 2)
print('recall', (sum(pos_recall)/n + sum(neg_recall)/n) / 2)
print('f-measure', (sum(pos_fmeasure)/n + sum(neg_fmeasure)/n) / 2)
print('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most elegant, but guess the most simple fix would be setting it to 0 and the actual value if not None, e.g.:

```
cv_pos_precision = 0
if precision(refsets['Positive'], testsets['Positive']):
    cv_pos_precision = precision(refsets['Positive'], testsets['Positive'])
```

And for the others as well, of course.

Comment: That might work, but would setting it to zero lower the average of the recall? From what I understand, recall = tp/(tp + fn). But I can't quite understand it from a set's perspective as implemented in nltk so I'm not sure if setting it to zero is the correct choice.

Comment: Fair point. Not sure what would be the methodologically correct way of doing this, guess there must be tons of scientific papers on this. You could also consider only appending a score to your precision and recall lists if it's not None, and then instead of doing `sum(pos_precision)/n` you would do `sum(pos_precision)/len(pos_precision)`